# JTabbedPane not displaying JPanel properly

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtabbedpane

I am trying to add a JPanel to a tab. However it does not display the button components or toolbars ive added to the panel. I am new to this so might be doing it completely wrong. Any advice would be appreciated.

Something like this:

```
public class JTabbedPaneFrame extends JFrame  
{

   public JTabbedPaneFrame()
   {


      JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(); 
      SortPanel p = new SortPanel();
      panel p1 = new Panel();



      tabbedPane.addTab( "Tab One", null, p1, "First Panel" ); 
      add( tabbedPane );
}
```

Comment: Why is the `SortPanel` never used for anything?

Comment: Consider making a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for better help

Comment: Cheers. I tried to edit it but it made my question even more incomprehensible.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the tabbed pane to another JPanel, then add that JPanel to the JFrame:

```
tabbedPane.addTab( "Tab One", null, p1, "First Panel" );    
JPanel anotherPanel = new JPanel();
anotherPanel.add(tabbedPane);
add(anotherPanel);
```